Faithful traces on reduced $C^*$-algebra of a measured groupoid
Let $G$ be a measured étale groupoid with quasi-invariant measure $\mu$ (that induces the reduced $C^* $-algebra, meaning it has full support) with associated equivalent measures $\nu,\nu^{-1}$.

Is there any way to define a faithful trace on $C^*_r(G)$?

There is an article of Li and Zhang called "Tracial states on groupoid $C^∗ $-algebras and essential freeness" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.15546) that does it in the case of $\mu$ being invariant, that is, the modular function being identically 1:
If we let $E: C_r^* (G) \rightarrow C_0(X)$ be the canonical expectation and $\tau_\mu: C_0(G^0) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ being integration against $\mu$, then $\text{tr} = E \circ \tau_\mu$ is a faithful trace on $C_r^* (G)$.
On the other hand, Anantharaman-Delaroche in the paper "The Haagerup property for discrete measured groupoids" (https://hal.science/hal-01138882) defines a faithful state on $\text{vN}(G)$ given by
$$
\varphi(T) = \langle \chi_{G^0},T\chi_{G^0} \rangle_{L^2(G,\nu^{-1})},
$$
but I think this does not yield a trace in the case that $\mu$ is not invariant.

Is your groupoid etale? If not, then you will get counterexamples among reduced group Cstar algebras of certain Lie groups. I can supply more details if this is relevant.

@YemonChoi Yes sorry I forgot to write that, thank you for pointing it out.
